# recursively rename files and replacing characters

Tags: bash, replace, find, filenames

In directory `~/foo/` there are some file/directory names which I want to to replace recursively using a bash script.

I want to replace every occurrence of `space` to `.` in **directory** names. Also, every occurrence of `space` to `-` in **file** names.

I have search similar questions and all of that use the command `find`, but I was not able find a way to use it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To replace in directories you could try this:

```
find ~/foo -type d -name "* *" -execdir perl-rename -v 's/ /./g' '{}' \+
```

And for files:

```
find ~/foo -type f -name "* *" -exec perl-rename -v 's/ /-/g' '{}' \;
```

**Options used**:

- `-type [fd]` to specify file or directory.
- `-name` to only match the directories/files with `space`
- `-exec\-execdir` to execute a command, in this case, `perl-rename`

**NOTE**

Depending in your S.O. you could use just `rename` instead of `perl-rename`.

Comment: If the only answer, which happens to be the accepted answer, is going to be downvoted, at the very least comment why!

Comment: On most Linux distributions, the`rename` (or `perl-rename`) command is not available by default